# jquery drop at top, not cursor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jquery drag/drop for a scheduling system. I have a with rows for time (15min interval) and columns for workers.

The events are divs , position absolute inside the cells, and their height corresponds to the time-length of the event; so an event flows on top of several 15-min cells.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5ukpngp/

```
$('.event').draggable({
  opacity: .7,
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: 'invalid',
});
$('td').droppable({
  hoverClass: "hover",
  tolerance: "pointer",

  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (false === dropped) {
   $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
  dropped = true;
  $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).appendTo($(this));
 }
},
activate: function(event, ui) {
 dropped = false;
  }
});
```

When I pick up a div, specifying a task, the top of the task ends at the cell where the cursor were when dropping.

So if I pick up the task at the bottom, then when I move the task to start at say 8:00, the cursor might be at 9:15. then I drop the task, and it moves to start at 9:15.

Is it possible to specify that the div is considered to be dropped at the top of the div, not at where it is picked up?

Also, could a draggable div be made non-droppable, so it is not possible to drop one task on top of another, or should the backend take care of that?

EDIT:
Idea: It works properly when the task is grabbed at the top line.
What if when "picking up the post-it", it moves downwards so the cursor is positioned at the top line?

EDIT2:
Here it is; top of movable div snaps to the cursor.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5ukpngp/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy one!

First, you have to evaluate the dragged element height on drag `start`.
Then, on `drop`, you have to get the drop row index and cell index...

And based on the dragged element height, you can find the right cell in the right row where you really want the element to be appended.

So here is the code:
And your [**JSFiddle** updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/no6xj9az/).

```
// Drag element height, determined on drag start and used on drop.
var dragElHeight;

$('.event').draggable({
  opacity: .7,
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: 'invalid',

  // Get the dragged element height.
  start: function(e){
    dragElHeight = Math.round($(e.target).height()/19);     // 19px is the td height in CSS
    console.log(dragElHeight);
  },

});

$('td').droppable({
  hoverClass: "hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {

    // Get cell indexes... And calculate the "real" target cell to be apended.
    var thisRowIndex = $(this).parent("tr").index()+1;
    var thisCellIndex = $(this).index()-1;
    var realTargetRow = $(this).closest("table").find("tr").eq(thisRowIndex-dragElHeight);

    if (false === dropped) {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
      dropped = true;
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo( realTargetRow.find("td").eq(thisCellIndex) );    // Append is here.
    }
  },
  activate: function(event, ui) {
    dropped = false;
  }
});
```

For your other question about defining some `td` as "non-droppable"...

It can be done. But this is quite a challenge.
You will have to evaluate which `td` are covered by an element and mark them as "occupied".
Then on drop, you will have to check if the target AND all other `td` that would be covered by this dragged element are "occupied" to allow the drop.

To "mark" the `td`, you could use [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)...

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it does not work properly. For instance, if I move the big task 1 to 8:00, it goes to the bottom.

Comment: If you make an effort to understand how the calculation is made... You will be able to prevent this. What I coded for you is to place the bottom of an event where you drag it. Now, if the calculation fails because this move is impossible... You have to work on it. I do not code for free here. I just give help. You now have the way to do it and you can complete it.

Comment: I made a modification, where the top of the div snaps to the cursor, 
Seems more intuitive,.